# Выбор типа DataSource

Tags: java, android, json, pagination

Я хочу получить JSON с большим количеством данных и реализовать в приложении отображение этих данных с пагинацией. Сервер не принимает никаких параметров, а просто отдает по ссылке JSON следующего вида:

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "type_id": "135",
        "id": "1408",
        "name": "Epos Passion 3403.193.24.15.25",
        "src": "http:\/\/cn34581.tmweb.ru\/images\/watch\/Epos_Passion_3403.193.24.15.25\/3403_193_24_15_25.jpg"
    },
    ...
    {
        "type_id": "78",
        "id": "1715",
        "name": "\u0420\u0430\u0437\u044a\u0435\u043c firewire",
        "src": "http:\/\/cn34581.tmweb.ru\/images\/cms\/data\/firewire6_to_firewire41.jpg"
    }
],
"success": 1}
```

Подойдет ли мне PageKeyedDataSource или надо использовать другой вид DataSource? Язык разработки Java

Если у кого-то есть пример с реализацией подобного - буду рад ему.

Андроид только изучаю, потому буду рад предельно разжеванным ответам.

Comment: Если сервер не принимает никаких параметров, то как Вы определите какую страницу (набор данных) отдавать?

Comment: Предполагалось, что будет доступен сразу весь JSON, а загружаться будет несколько итемов по конфигу .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE). Затем будет сравниваться по id oldItem и newItem и загружаться следующая порция итемов. Или так реализовать не выйдет?